# Differences in where you place dependencies in project.json file of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I was just looking at the `project.json` file in one of my ASP.NET Core projects and noticed there are two different areas to list dependencies.

One inside the `frameworks` node and the other is a `dependencies` node. Why/when would/should you place the dependencies in one location over the other?

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "My Class Library",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet5.4": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is very easy. You can have **different** dependencies for different frameworks.

In some cases the specified dependence exist in *different versions* for different frameworks.

In another case the specified dependency like `System.Runtime` needed be not included as all. The problem is here the DLL is separate module in .NET Core (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Runtime)), but the `dnx46` or `dnx451` contains the implemented methods *inside of* .Net framework. One don't need to include no *external* (additional) dll. Thus you need don't include `System.Runtime` package in the the `dnx451` part of the dependencies or as the common dependency. Thus `System.Runtime` is [framework-specific dependencies](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html?highlight=frameworkassemblies#framework-specific-dependencies).

In some seldom cases you can include the dependency in the form `"dnx451": "frameworkAssemblies": { "System.Runtime": "" }}` to skip including of `System.Runtime` if it was erroneously required (see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34136228/315935)). Typically one uses `frameworkAssemblies` to reference to assemblies from Global Assembly Cache (GAC) **without** redistributing it (see [the documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html?highlight=frameworkassemblies#assembly-references)).

Comment: I understand that if your targeting multiple frameworks you can specify different versions for each framework. But what about the pure `dependencies` node that is not tied to any framework?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: It's **common** dependency used for every targeting framework. For example `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` is not included as the part of some framework and the package supports `dotnet5.4`, `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`. Thus you can include it as common dependency.

Comment: I see, can you amend your answer for that so it address both parts of the question?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What "both parts of the question" you mean? `project.json` have two places for including dependencies: `"dependencies"` includes common dependencies over all `"frameworks"` which you use and `"frameworks"."frameworkName"."dependencies"` includes dependencies which are used only during building the target for the specified framework. I prescribed examples when such  framework-specific dependencies could be required.

Comment: You answer explains why there is a dependencies section for the framework node but does not explain the usage of the dependences node by it's self.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete: Could you be more precise? You wrote "the dependencies node by it's self". What you mean? It doesn't exist. It seems that you still misunderstand what `dependencies` do, but I can't help you because you express yourself not clear enough and I have to guess what you mean.

Comment: If you look at the code I posted there is a `frameworks` node that has it's own `dependencies` node (frameworks -> dotnet5.4 => dependencies). After that node there is just `dependencies`